# Converting Arduino LCD Programs to Serial I2C LCD code

Tags: lcd, arduino-nano

I just got a Serial LCD and wanted to test it out with a game. I found this [site](http://eturnerx.blogspot.com/2012/08/arduino-lcd-hunt-wumpus-conversion.html) with game conversions and wanted to use [this game](http://eturnerx.com/files/arduino/003_wumpus_hunt_eturnerx_arduino_lcd.html).  However since my serial LCD use the LiquidCrystalic2 library the code in its current state won't work. Is there a simple method of converting or porting liquidcrystal to LiquidCrystalic2? Or if someone knows of a simple game in regards to hardware that uses a serial lcd and could direct me to a link that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my lcd working on I2C following the steps in this link http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=128635.0